# onchange event listener for ui:inputSelect not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, event, onchange

I am trying to implement a picklist using the Aura component `<ui:inputSelect>` with a change event listner. But I see that the change event listener (JavaScript function) is not getting registered with the component.

Below is my component markup

[image: Component Markup]

And this is the code in my JS controller:

```
onChangeFunction: function(component) {
 console.log(component.get('v.value'));
}
```

Please see that in Chrome web inspector, there is no change event listener registered for the component. So, if I change the value of the picklist component, the onchange event listener function "onChangeFunction" in my controller is not getting invoked. This is my problem

[image]

Comment: Did you try the below answers ?

Comment: Hi Praveen, in Chrome web inspector, I see that there is no change event listener registered for the component. So, if I change the value of the picklist component, the onchange event listener function "onChangeFunction" in my controller is not getting invoked. This is my problem. I have posted the screenshot from Chrome Web Inspector as an answer. Please check.

Comment: Ok let me check at my dev org and will let you know.

Comment: I tried at my end and it works fine.See the updated answer.

Comment: Kiran, have you tried the sample code in the answer? Let us know what behaviour you see?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't given `value` attribute for the `<ui:select/>` component, you could do `selectCmp.get("v.value")` since it is internally available.Click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm) to find more attributes that are available in the component.

```
onChangeFunction: function(component,event) {
    console.log(event.getSource().get('v.value')); //only works for aura:component like <ui:inputSelect/>
}
```

If the value is attribute is binded to `aura:attribute`, you could do below:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedRecType" type="String" access="private" />
<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.selectedRecType}" change="{!c.onChangeFunction}">
 ...
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Method in **Controller.js** should look like this:

```
onChangeFunction: function(component,event) {
    console.log(component.get('v.selectedRecType'));
}
```

**--Update--**

I tried to reproduce the issue,but `change` function works at my end.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="contactLevel" type="List" access="private"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="levels" label="Contact Levels" change="{!c.onChangeFunction}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactLevel}" var="level">
             <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!level}" label="{!level}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp,event,helper){
        cmp.set("v.contactLevel",['Primary Contact', 'Secondary Contact', 'Other']);
    },
    onChangeFunction : function(cmp,event){
       console.log(event.getSource().get("v.value"));        
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, My problem is that the event listener function is not getting registered with the component.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript controller function, you should find the ui:inputSelect component first, and then get the value of that:

```
onChangeFunction: function(component) {
    console.log(component.find('InputSelectDynamic').get('v.value'));
}
```

I've tested this in Google Chrome, and it works just fine.

Comment: Hi  I tried same and got error saying "Unknown controller action 'onSelectChange"